# How in vba to click a link on a web page

Tags: vba, web, hyperlink, click

I am trying to automate the login on a website. So far I managed to let the script type in a user-name and password and also click on a login button. This works just fine and I am logged into the website.
Next step would be to click on some links to get to the right page where I can enter the search data the site needs to find the data for me.

This is the HTML-code of the tag involved:

```html
<a title="Klik hier voor de dienst Kadaster-on-line" class="serviceAvailable" href="https://kadaster-on-line.kadaster.nl/default.asp" target="_self" ng-if="!menuItem.items" ng-repeat-start="menuItem in menuItems">Kadaster-on-line</a>
```

I have been trying to get VBA to click on a link but can't get in right. This is my latest attempt:

```
Set alle_keuzes = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each keuze_voor_kadaster In alle_keuzes        
    If keuze_voor_kadaster.getAttribute("title") = "Klik hier voor de dienst Kadaster-on-line" Then
        keuze_voor_kadaster.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next keuze_voor_kadaster
```

What would be a proper way to do this?

Comment: What does can't get it right mean? Is there an error? Does nothing happen?  Is there a parent frame/iframe surrounding your target element?

Answer (score 2):

The link should be selectable by

```
ie.document.querySelector("a[title='Klik hier voor de dienst Kadaster-on-line']").click
```

You could also try:

```
ie.document.querySelector("a[title='Klik hier voor de dienst Kadaster-on-line']").FireEvent "onclick"
```

If you are getting an object not set/found error then:

1) Inspect the html to see ifparent frame/iframe tag which you element is found inside of.

In that case you may need syntax similar to:

```
ie.document.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(frameIndexGoesHere).contentDocument.querySelector("a[title='Klik hier voor de dienst Kadaster-on-line']")
```

Use `getElementById` if the frame/iframe has an id.

2) Check you are waiting long enough for the element to be present before clicking. If that is the case ensure you have the following for page load and a loop to wait for element to be present:

After navigating to URL

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
Dim ele As Object, t As Date
t = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ele = ie.document.querySelector("a[title='Klik hier voor de dienst Kadaster-on-line']")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
Loop While ele Is Nothing

If Not ele Is Nothing Then ele.Click
```

Comment: The first two solutions provided a 424 error (object required). So it seems that I should indeed have a wider look at the HTML code.

Comment: I made a few typos which I have now corrected. Try the bottom loop version and and also check for parent frame/iframe tag. If you can copy the entire page HTML into a https://pastebin.com/  (if not private content) I can inspect that.

Comment: I did this little project in Python at first and now, since this is no longer supported, I have to do this in VBA.

Comment: I enclose the entire HTML of the page as requested. I also enclose the Python so you can see how the script continues. https://pastebin.com/swLt2Jrt https://pastebin.com/TiaDadAh

Comment: Does your python script work and you simply need a translation or does the py script detail next steps?

Comment: you could potentially just extract the link and use that: https://kadaster-on-line.kadaster.nl/default.asp   rather than do the click. Is that an option? The selector I wrote works so the bottom answer I gave should work.

Comment: The Python script works perfectly. I am no longer allowed to use Python for these kind of problems. So I only need to translate the script into VBA. I am not much of an expert in VBA. I’ll test your solution tomorrow.

Comment: No worries. I will have a go at translating the python script tonight/tomorrow.

Comment: And are you allowed to use selenium basic for vba?

Comment: No unfortunately not. This is what makes things complicated. The use of selenium in Python makes controliing a browser rather easy. I presume this is also the case in VBA. That is why I am struggling to get a working script in VBA. But I am not giving up. I keep on trying and googling for potential solutions. Yesterday I think getting past this one problem would be enough to get the rest of the script to work. All remaining elements have id’s to work with.

Comment: It’s just part of your success main be down to using selenium. I can translate to “vanilla” vba though, in as far as is possible.

Comment: I know the importance of selenium in web scraping or web automation. I use it in Python myself. However in this case, due to new EU privacy legislation I am no longer allowed to use Python and I am also stuk with a limited Excel version. It is a complete paranoia. I appreciate your help so far but you don’t need to go as far a translating my entire script. The problem is limited to just this one click. The rest seems to be fairly straigh forward giving the id’s in the HTML. I’ll spent some time on this week and whenever I find the solution I will share it here for you to see.

Comment: Do you need to click if you can extract the URL?

Comment: I have managed to get my code to work. In the end I used this code:

Comment: Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")).

Comment: Great to hear though if adding a wait like that works I wonder why my timed loop doesn’t work? Perhaps the element is present before clickable.

Comment: QHarr: I am not quit sure but I am glad to see that everything works just fine. I am not really into VBA but this task tiggered me to spent a lot more time into VBA. This is fun too. I suppose my question was more super basic for you. Thanks to all the people above I learned quite a bit.