# VBA to checkbox on IE

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm unable to tick/click checkbox on IE (through VBA) and it seems I have tried a lot of methods already. Can you please advise?

FYI Elements:

```
<div class="bordered_table" id="mig-to-prod">
    <div class="edl_checkbox floatleft">

            <input type="hidden" name="_selectAllConfigs" value="visible" />    
            <label class="edl_chb">         
                <input type="checkbox" name="selectAllConfigs"

                onclick="changeDropDown(this.form);">
                <span></span>
```

The checkbox is `edl_chb`

I have tried:

```
Html.querySelector("a[title=edl_chb]").Click
Html.querySelector("a[title='edl_chb']").Click
Html.querySelector("a[title='edl_chb']")(0).Click
Html.querySelector("a[title='edl_chb']")(1).Click
```

I have also tried to `getelemtsbyclassname`

Comment: Can you include the URL?

Comment: Am afraid I can't, it's a corporate website (of some firm) that only works after security login.Sorry

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Are you selecting the correct element but simply no check appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to allow enough time for page to load. This includes having the following after the .Navigate2 line.

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

For other approaches see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320024/how-in-vba-to-click-a-link-on-a-web-page/53320761#53320761).

You could try an attribute = value combination of

```
ie.document.querySelector("[type=checkbox][name=selectAllConfigs]").click
```

Or

```
ie.document.querySelector("[type=checkbox][name=selectAllConfigs]").FireEvent "onclick"
```

Comment: In the first case I have received an error 424 Object Required, in the second case the same.

Comment: Are you 1) Leaving a sufficient wait for page load before this? Can you show the rest of your code? 2) Have you checked the element is not inside a parent frame/iframe? Some further info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53320761/6241235)

Comment: Hi, you were right, I forgot about allowing the page to load in!    Do While IEx.Busy Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now) Loop, solved everything and the first line (solution) worked perfectly! Thanks a lot QHarr