# Automate pressing "Buttons" on web pages

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

Can someone help please, i can't seem to get the below to work

```
Sub Automate_IE_Load_Page()
'This will load a webpage in IE
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    'Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    URL = "https://Whatever"   'Not putting the URL up here
    IE.Navigate URL
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop


    IE.Document.getElementbyid("menuoptionCell_Excel2007+").Click '(Fails here)
    'Set Button = IE.Document.getElementbyid("menuoptionCell_Excel2007+")
    'Button.Click

End Sub
```

i have also tried

```
   IE.Document.getElementsbyClass("contextMenuOptionTextCell")(0).Click
```

It is saying i need an object. I have tried different methods but none seem to work. I will say i am using the word "Button" loosely as its not actually a button, but not sure what it is called. Below are the identities used on the web page, and i'm not totally sure which i need to press, but neither seem to work

```
<td class="contextMenuOptionTextCell">
    <span class="contextMenuOptionText">Excel 2007+</span></td>

<td id="menuoptionCell_Excel2007+" style="vertical-align: top; width: 16px;"></td>
```

thank you

Mike

Comment: As a minimum have  While ie .Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend to allow for page load. And consider a [timed loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53320761/6241235) to attempt to set a reference to the object

Comment: Can you verify that `IE.Document.getElementsbyClass("contextMenuOptionTextCell")(0)` or `getElementbyid("menuoptionCell_Excel2007+")` actually returns an object?

Comment: You are trying to click TD tag. If you click on TD tag by mouse then nothing happen. I suggest you to create a HTML button inside your TD tag and than try to click the button.

Comment: Thanks guys, this isnt a web page i have built, i'm trying to learn how to automate web activity, basically trying to automate the extraction of reports with out an API. I'm not that clued up on it, so don't really know where to start, but on researching the web this is what i have found, or variants of this, and i cant get this to work.